# Error 500 when connecting/authenticating to STS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, wif

Our application uses WIF 3.5 to authenticate in a STS server. The first time it works as it should, but when the session expires and the user goes back to the login page and tries to log in again, it stops at the issuer URL and give us a blank screen. This problem started to happen after we migrated from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012.

The provider is SAML 1.1 and the issuer URL where it stops is like this:

https://IssuerUrl?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https://OurApplicationRealm&wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3dctl00%2524ContentPlaceHolder%2524loginControl%2524FederatedPassiveSignInControl&wct=2016-01-12T21%3a23%3a41Z

What we already tried:

- Converting the application to .Net 4.5 and using System.IdentityModel instead of Microsoft.IdentityModel
- FREB logs on STS server shows these errors:
  [image]

[image]

[image]

- When we use tools like Fiddler or iDNA and try to reproduce the problem, strangely it does not occur

Comment: You have to provide more details, at least - which specific provider are you using and what specific url leads to a blank page. Also, if the problem is at the "issuer URL" (the STS?), why would you try to convert the app to .net 4.5 if this is not your app that fails?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Updated the question with the info requested.

Comment: SAML protocol is 1.1 or SAML token is 1.1? IIRC, 2012 only supports SAML 2.0 protocol.

Comment: @nzpcmad The SAML token is 1.1. The protocol is the WS-Federation.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!